# Play framework: load javascript only on specific method calls

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

I'm working on an application which involves a lot of ajax calls, and I want each of these ajax snippets only to be loaded when specific pages are requested. Often the ajax calls will involve reloading the content, and I don't want this to happen on every page

Any idea if Play! has some solution for this? Or how I could implement something myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you can limit your required snippets in the view by setting `moreScripts` to your js files (with a corresponding `#{get 'moreScripts' /}` in main.html).

Another solution would be to use the info from the [request](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play/mvc/Http.Request.html) (e.g.  `#{if request.action =="Application.login"}'`.
The question is if you can keep your code clean this way.

I *think* you could also do this using a FastTag.

Comment: How does `moreScripts` work inside the js file? And is it possible to have play! render the JS files too, so it renders `#{jsAction}`?

Comment: I meant you could use `moreScripts` inside your HTML to load the required AJAX snippets (from .js-files).

It should be possible to write a renderer for JS files, but I'm not sure how you would combine it with the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to render JavaScript files dynamically, as that will make them un-cacheable, forcing the browser to halt rendering until the JavaScript is loaded on every page render.

You could place the Ajax functionality in a function inside a JavaScript file, and invoke it with a one-liner script from each relevant page. As suggested by Marius you can also encapsulate this one-liner (and the <link> tag) with a Play! fast tag.